# Element algebraic over field iff algebraic over field extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field, and $K$ a finite extension of $F$. I want to show that any element algebraic over $K$ is algebraic over $F$, and conversely.

Well, if $a$ is algebraic over $F$, we can write $c_0+c_1a+\ldots+c_na^n=0$ for some $c_0,\ldots,c_n\in F$. But $c_0,\ldots,c_n\in K$, so $a$ is algebraic over $K$.

Now suppose $a$ is algebraic over $K$, so we can write $c_0+c_1a+\ldots+c_na^n=0$ for some $c_0,\ldots,c_n\in K$. What to do then?

Comment: @GitGud $\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: My bad, sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$F(a) \subset K(a)$$

And $[K(a):F]=[K(a):K] [K:F] < \infty$. From here you should be able to get that

$$[F(a):F]< \infty \,.$$

Comment: The last one using $[K(a):F]=[K(a):F(a)][F(a):F]$, right?

Comment: @Kunal Or even simpler, any subspace of a finite dimensional $F$-vector space is finite... Which in this case, is the same as saying that a subextension of a finite extension must be finite ...

Comment: But $F(a)\subset K(a)$ per se assumes $a$ is algebraic over $F$, a circular reasoning.

Comment: @hchar $F \subset K$ implies $F(a) \subset K(a)$ no matter if $a$ is algebraic or not.